# How to get the index of a multidimensional array and splice that array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, splice

There is a [problem](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures/iterate-through-all-an-arrays-items-using-for-loops) in FreeCodeCamp.I'm not here to search solution to that problem. While trying to solve the problem I found some lines of my code do not work. I can not understand why that is not working. So I am here to ask YOU, good people, to help me.

## problem

There is a function. I will pass an array and a number to that function. And what I need to return is also an array.
The array is a multidimensional array.

**what I want to do**

First of all I want to check if the inner or subarray contains the number i passed while calling the function. If that contains i need the index of that number in that subarray. Then I want to delete the number from that subarray using splice(). At last I wanted to return an array where there are sub arrays in it but none of them contain the given number.

**where i am stuck in**

But I am stuck in finding the index of the number in sub arrays, how can i use splice() to delete the number? Is it possible to do this way? Do you have any better suggestion for me?

**my code**

where for the first for loop it just prints -1
for the second loop, it prints the index of the array,not the index of the subarray.

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
    let newArr = [];
    // Only change code below this line
    newArr = [...arr]
    let L = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        //  -------1-----------
        for (elem in newArr[i]) {
            console.log(newArr[i].indexOf(elem));
        }
    }
    console.log('first loop ends')
    for (let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        //  --------2---------
        for (let j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++) {
            if (newArr[i][j] == elem) {
                console.log(newArr[i].indexOf(elem))
            }
        }

        // Only change code above this line
        return newArr;
    }
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
    let newArr = [];
    // Only change code below this line
    newArr = [...arr]
    let L = arr.length;
    // for (let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    //     //  -------1-----------
    //     for (elem in newArr[i]) {
    //         console.log(newArr[i].indexOf(elem));
    //     }
    // }
    console.log('first loop ends')
    for (let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        //  --------2---------
        for (let j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++) {
            if (newArr[i][j] == elem) {
                console.log(newArr[i].indexOf(elem))
            }
        }

        // Only change code above this line
        return newArr;
    }
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Comment: The main problem here is that you're only logging stuff but never pushing anything to `newArr`. You have also moved `return newArr;` inside your 2nd for loop, which means the function ends after the first iteration.

Comment: In your first loop, try with `for (elem of newArr[i])` (note `of` vs `in`).  This way `elem` will be the element of `newArr[i]`, rather than its index.  However, you then have the problem of `indexOf(elem)` selecting only the *first* index of the element, and it'll not find both 3s in your sub-array `[3, 2, 3]`.  For using splice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: Also, a word of caution... your array copy with the spread operator at the top `newArr = [...arr]` will copy the outer array, but the inner sub-arrays will reference the same sub-arrays as in the input `arr`.  Any splicing you do on the sub-arrays of `newArr` will mutate the same sub-arrays of the input `arr`.  The outer array copy at the top implies this might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing values from an array you don't want to use a mutating method like `.splice()` -- the original array will change. If `.splice()` removes a number, the length of the array decreases and all indexes at and after the index of the removed number will shift (unless you replace that number instead). The non-mutating methods such as `filter()` and `.map()` makes a copy of the array and returns the copy leaving the original array intact. See this [article](https://doesitmutate.xyz) for a easy reference of what mutates and what doesn't.

You could simplify the process of removing a given number from an array of arrays by using `.map()` on each sub-array and `.filter()` each sub-array with the condition of returning only numbers that do not equal the given number.

```js
const data = [[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]];

const filterCols = (target, arrArr) => 
  arrArr.map(sub => sub.filter(num => num !== target));

console.log(filterCols(3, data));
```